# Does pvcreate erase data when applied to existing partition?

Tags: partition, lvm, data-recovery

I was running out of space in my volume group (VG) called "linuxvg" and therefore chose to add one more physical volume (PV) to it, called /dev/sda11 (already existing in partition table). I simply ran:

```
    pvcreate /dev/sda11
    pvextend linuxvg /dev/sda11
```

The problem is that /dev/sda11 was also my root partition and this operation made it stop working (I was directed to emergency shell instead of booting). I made the mistake of thinking that one partition could be used for a VG and as a normal volume at the same time.

I tried to revert the process by doing

```
    vgreduce linuxvg /dev/sda11
    pvremove /dev/sda11
```

which seemed to revert everything to the original state, but it seems like all the files from my /dev/sda11 are lost. Since "filesystem" was empty when running

```
    lsblk -f
```

I created it again using

```
    mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda11
```

with no success.

I would really appreciate your help, I have been stuck on this for too long!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A given partition can only be used for one thing at a time, as you’ve realised. You pretty much need to restore from backups at this point, or reinstall from scratch.

(You *could* try [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) but unless you specifically have data you need to recover, it’s probably not worth it; I doubt it would recover your binaries and configuration files. You could also run `strings` on `/dev/sda11` to extract any remaining configuration information.)